# Unbind SPC from org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-agenda

I would like to unbind the space key in the org-agenda. Currently it is scrolling the org-mode file to the currently selected item in the org-agenda (`org-agenda-show-and-scroll-up`).

I am currently using SPC globally for command, and I would like to SPC to be bound to that function in the org-agenda, instead of `org-agenda-show-and-scroll-up`.

I have been unsuccessful in unbinding this key so far.

Any idea?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried that did not work

Comment: Have you tried `(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda (define-key org-agenda-mode-map [?\s] nil))`?

Comment: Hey @tobias - in my opinion this is actually the answer.  Personally I would use `(kbd "SPC")` instead of `[?\s]`, but this is a matter of taste.